# How to extract a number from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point, int

How do you extract a number from a string to be able to manipulate it? The number could be either an `int` or a `float`. For example if the string is `"flour, 100, grams"` or `"flour, 100.5, grams"` then extracting the number `100` or `100.5`.

**Code**:

```
string  = "flour, 100, grams"
numbers = [int(x) for x in string.split(",")]
print(numbers)
```

**Output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lewis/Documents/extracting numbers.py", line 2, in <module>
    numbers = [int(x) for x in string.split(",")]
 File "/Users/lewis/Documents/extracting numbers.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
   numbers = [int(x) for x in string.split(",")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'flour'
```

Comment: You'd do it the same way as in any other version of Python. What, exactly, is in your strings? What do you expect to get out of them? What have you tried yourself yet but didn't work? How did it fail?

Comment: And the other half of Martijn's question? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the structure of your strings, when you use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the string into a list of three strings, you should only take one of the three elements:

```
>>> s = "flour, 100, grams"
>>> s.split(",")
['flour', ' 100', ' grams']
>>> s.split(",")[1] # index the middle element (Python is zero-based)
' 100'
```

You can then use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) to convert that string into a number:

```
>>> float(s.split(",")[1])
100.0
```

If you can't be as certain as to the structure of the strings, you could use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (regular expressions) to extract numbers and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert them all:

```
>>> import re
>>> map(float, re.findall(r"""\d+ # one or more digits
                              (?: # followed by...
                                  \. # a decimal point 
                                  \d+ # and another set of one or more digits
                              )? # zero or one times""",
                          "Numbers like 1.1, 2, 34 and 15.16.",
                          re.VERBOSE))
[1.1, 2.0, 34.0, 15.16]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried try except blocks around your type cast which will throw away the string flour but keep the 100

```
string = 'flour, 100, grams'
numbers = []

    for i in string.split(','):
    try:
        print int(i)
        numbers.append(i)
    except: pass
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how this should be implemented? It can't be trivially dropped into a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple and best way to extract numbers from a string. N number of digits you can extract from a string by using following code.

-Get integer numbers -

```
import re
s = 'flour, 100, grams, 200HC'
print(re.findall('\d+', s))
```

-Get float Numbers -

```
import re
map(float, re.findall(r"""\d+ # one or more digits
                          (?: # followed by...
                              \. # a decimal point 
                              \d+ # and another set of one or more digits
                          )? # zero or one times""",
                      "Numbers like 1.1, 2, 34 and 15.16.",
                      re.VERBOSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a little conversion function like the one below which attempts to convert its argument first into an `int`, then into a `float`, then into a `complex` (just extending the example). If you wish to obtain/retain the most appropriate type for the input, then the order of attempted conversion is important as an `int` will successfully be converted to a `float`, but not vice versa, so you need to attempt to convert the input into an `int` first.

```
def convert_to_number(n):
    candidate_types = (int, float, complex)
    for t in candidate_types:
        try:
            return t(str(n))
        except ValueError:
#            pass
            print "{!r} is not {}".format(n, t)    # comment out if not debugging
    else:
        raise ValueError('{!r} can not be converted to any of: {}'.format(n, candidate_types))

>>> s = "flour, 100, grams"
>>> n = convert_to_number(s.split(',')[1])
>>> type(n)
<type 'int'>
>>> n
100

>>> s = "flour, 100.123, grams"
>>> n = convert_to_number(s.split(',')[1])
' 100.123' is not <type 'int'>
>>> type(n)
<type 'float'>
>>> n
100.123

>>> n = convert_to_number('100+20j')
'100+20j' is not <type 'int'>
'100+20j' is not <type 'float'>
>>> type(n)
<type 'complex'>
>>> n
(100+20j)

>>> n = convert_to_number('one')
'one' is not <type 'int'>
'one' is not <type 'float'>
'one' is not <type 'complex'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ctn.py", line 10, in convert_to_number
    raise ValueError('{!r} can not be converted to any of: {}'.format(n, candidate_types))
ValueError: 'one' can not be converted to any of: (<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'complex'>)
```

You could use regular expressions to pluck out the numeric fields from each line of input as per jonrsharpe's answer.